# Error while parallelizing a List[String] taken from Java and used in Scala to create a RDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

```
var g = Graphx.graph() // return an Object with 2 Lists : List<Edge> edgeArray 
                      //                                  List<String> vertexArray  
val vertexRDD: RDD[(String)] = sc.parallelize(g.vertexArray)
```

type mismatch;

[**error**]  found   : java.util.List[String]

[**error**]  required: Seq[String]

[**error**] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.

[**error**]     val vertexRDD: RDD[(String)] = sc.parallelize(**g.vertexArray**)

Answer (score 1):

You should import the following:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

Then use

```
val vertexRDD: RDD[(String)] = sc.parallelize(g.vertexArray.asScala)
```